# Menu lateral no me funciona o no toma script

Tags: javascript, html5

Quisiera entender porque al hacer el menu que copio mas abajo, si cargo los estilos en la misma pagina funciona, y si los cargo con un css aparte no. Agradeceré si me pueden explicar xq y como solucionarlo con el css aparte.

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.menuprin {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #6D0D14;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.menuprin a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #A7988B;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

.menuprin a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.menuprin .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    position: fixed;
    display:block;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;    
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

#contiene {
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}

a {
  font-size: 38px;  
}

#frprincipal {
    position: fixed;
    display:block;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}

img#menu1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    top: -2px;
    left: 5px;
}


@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .menuprin {padding-top: 15px;}
  .menuprin a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<Link href="css/menu.css?<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script>
  function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("MenuPrincipal").style.width = "250px";
  }

  function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("MenuPrincipal").style.width = "0";
  }
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="MenuPrincipal" class="menuprin">
  <div id="contiene"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a></div>
  <br>

  <a href="#" onclick="closeNav();document.getElementById('frprincipal').src='datos1.php';" onclick="closeNav();document.getElementById('frprincipal').src='datos1.php';">Datos1</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="closeNav();document.getElementById('frprincipal').src='datos2.php';" onclick="closeNav();document.getElementById('frprincipal').src='datos2.php';">Datos2</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="closeNav();document.getElementById('frprincipal').src='datos3.php';" onclick="closeNav();document.getElementById('frprincipal').src='datos3.php';">Datos3</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="closeNav();document.getElementById('frprincipal').src='datos4.php';" onclick="closeNav();document.getElementById('frprincipal').src='datos4.php';">Datos4</a>
  

<div id="main">
  <iframe id="frprincipal" src="datos1.php">  
  </iframe>
</div>

<img id="menu1" src="img/menu.png" onclick="openNav()">
     
</body>
</html>
```

La idea es que es un menu desplegable. Gracias !

Comment: tiene que estar mal la ruta `css/menu.css`

Comment: hmm la ruta es correcta, me toma los estilos, por algun motivo no me muestra la imagen del menu , y no me doy cuenta que ocurre ..

Comment: `href="css/menu.css?<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>` que ruta es esta ?

Comment: El problema serán las prioridades de los estilos, compruébalo con la consola del navegador

Comment: @andygibbs eso lo pone para que el navegador no lo tome de la cache, supongo. En ese caso seria mejor `css/menu.css?<?= microtime() ?>`

Comment: @Emeeus vale no sabia aserca de ello y que ventaja hay con que el navegador no lo guarde en la cache?

Comment: @andygibbs sirve para que cuando desarrollas no tienes que hacer ctrl+r 20 veces ni nada para que cargue los nuevos estilos que acabas de cambiar. Debe haber técnicas mejores : )

Comment: @Emeeus gracias por el dato!!

Comment: Para los que mencionan la ventaja de no guardar en cache, en realidad esa es una desventaja. Si el script cambia de contenido debería cambiar de nombre también y el html debería apuntar al nuevo script. Esa es la manera correcta de aprovechar la cache del navegador y a la vez recibir un css actualizado sin que se quede pegada la versión anterior.

Answer (score 0):

para hacerlo te conviene utilizar Jquery, que es mucho mas simple, disfrutando de la funcion `toggle()` que lo unico que hace es cambiar la visibilidad del elemento deseado, le podes pasar como parametro los ms que queres que dure la transicion, tambien te permite de pasarle  "slow" "fast", que son velocidades predeterminadas por ellos.
igualmente tenias un par de `<div>` que no estaban cerrados,  aca te paso el codigo, espero que te sirva!

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
.menuprin {
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #6D0D14;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.2s;
    display: none;
}

.menuprin > a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #A7988B;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

.menuprin > a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.menuprin .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    position: fixed;
    display:block;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;    
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

#contiene {
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}

a {
  font-size: 38px;  
}

#frprincipal {
    position: fixed;
    display:block;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}

img#menu1 {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    top: -2px;
    left: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .menuprin {padding-top: 15px;}
  .menuprin a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale1">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="style.css?<?php =microtime() ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
           $(document).ready ( function () {
                $(document).on("click", "#menu1", function() {
                    $("#MenuPrincipal").toggle();
                });
          
                $(document).on("click", "#MenuPrincipal a" , function() {
                    $("#MenuPrincipal").toggle();
                });
           });
        </script>
        <img id="menu1" src="img/menu.png" >
        <div id="MenuPrincipal" class="menuprin">
           
                <a href="#">prueba</a>
                <a href="#">prueba</a>
                <a href="#">prueba</a>
                <a href="#">prueba</a>
            
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <iframe id="frprincipal" src="datos1.php"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<html>
```